# Resque - distributing job load evenly between several servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I have a Rails application with Resque doing background jobs on multiple servers. The jobs are different in terms of their resource needs, so I would like to limit the amount of jobs of particular type, each server can do. I want to be able to have multiple servers query the same Redis database.

Here is the scenario:
I have Server-1 and Server-2 connected to the same Redis database.

1) Each server should take 3 "Encoding" jobs and 5 "Parsing" jobs max (8 jobs total).

2) At a given moment Redis-server will have 10 jobs in "Encoding" queue and 12 jobs in "Parsing" queue available for Resque workers to process. I have 2 servers running, quering the same database.

QUESTION: How can I prevent Server-1 from taking 8 "Encoding" jobs and Server-2 taking the rest? In other words, how to restrict Server-1 to taking only 3 jobs from "Encoding" queue and 5 jobs from "Parsing" queue and have Server-2 do the same?

I want to keep the code universal so that I can deploy it to multiple servers without individual tweaking..

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can or should do at the redis level. You need a supervisor that sits in between the application requests to your redis instances. I've not written anything at production level for ruby for a long time so I cannot suggest a favourite candidate but I am sure there will be something in the ruby community for doing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You `cant` achieve this (I guess)  with a single rake task like this

rake resque:workers COUNT=8 QUEUE=encoding_queue,parsing_queue BACKGROUND=yes

But if you can bifurcate your rake task then you can

ON `SERVER-1`

`rake resque:workers COUNT=3 QUEUE=encoding_queue BACKGROUND=yes`

`rake resque:workers COUNT=5 QUEUE=parsing_queue  BACKGROUND=yes`

Repeat the same in ON `SERVER-2`

Hope this help